# Convert baud rate to words per minute

Tags: conversion, modem

I'm not sure if SuperUser is the best place to ask this.  But does anyone have a conversation for how many words per minute(wpm) to baud(bps)?  I was trying to figure out 300/1200/2400 bps to wpm but I seem to lack this crucial information.

Comment: Baud and bps are two different measurements. You seem to be asking about bps rather than baud. Additionally, you have not defined what you mean by 'word'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most purposes, "baud" and bits per second are considered synonymous, even though it is not technically accurate to use them interchangeably in all cases.

To convert bits per second to characters per second you must know the character size (including framing bits).  This is generally between 8 and 11 bits per character, depending on the protocol.  Then you must know how a "word" is defined.  Typically a "word" is defined as 5-10 characters, but there's no real standard.  (5 is used in typing tests, but other numbers are used in other contexts.)

But roughly:

```
CPS = BPS / 10;
WPM = (CPS / 5) * 60;
```

Or

```
WPM = ((BPS / 10) / 5) * 60;
```

Or

```
WPM = BPS * 1.2;
```